# Django through Docker Error: That IP address can't be assigned to

Tags: python, django, docker, server, ip

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 VM and trying to run my Django app through Docker container.

I successfully verified that my web is working. It runs if I just command on my machine. 
However, when I build image with my app and run the container, it does not work.
my Dockerfile has this CMD at the end.

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "my_VM_IP:8000]"
```

It gives me an error

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 21, 2018 - 20:50:44
Django version 1.11.13, using settings 'datahttptools.settings'
Starting development server at http://myVMip:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.
```

I was trying all the possible solutions by googling but I was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Django documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver the address is defaulted to 127.0.0.1 (loopback device) that is only reachable on the machine itself. In this scenario the Django server would be only reachable in the container itself. I guess you need the service reachable from your normal host system and therefore you should change the the command to:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

This will bind the server to all network interfaces with IPv4 at port 8000. In order to bind to offer IPv6 it has to be:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "[::]:8000"]
```